# Find parent by class

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<div id="aaa" class="p">
    <div id = "bbb">
        <div id="actor" onclick = "testParent(this)">
            test parent
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
testParent = function(obj){
    alert($(obj).parent(".p").id);
}
```

I think this should be alerting `aaa` but it doesn't.

Isn't this a way to find parent by class?

**Edit**
I know closest can do this but more specifically it is parent, isn't it? So there is no specific implementation from jquery for this?

[Here is fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/81ce38zv/)

Comment: [.closest(".p")](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: What do you mean by _there is no specific implementation from jquery for this_?`.p` is an ancestor not  a immediate [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/), You can also use `.parents()` but `.closest()` is better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
testParent = function(obj){
 alert($(obj).parents('.p').attr('id'));
}
```

It's pretty simple and short code.

Comment: This is the answer I was expecting. Every one else suggested `closest` that is true but `parents` in more specific as I am accessing `parent` for element. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use need to use `parents()` it will find matching parent with `class` `.p` and `attr()` will get you id of matched parent. See below code.

```js
testParent = function(obj){
    alert($(obj).parents(".p").attr("id"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="aaa" class="p">
    <div id = "bbb">
        <div id="actor" onclick = "testParent(this)">
            test parent
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `.closest()` and use the `obj` without the `$()`

It should be like this:

```
alert(obj.closest(".p").id);
```

```js
testParent = function(obj) {
  alert(obj.closest(".p").id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="aaa" class="p">
  <div id="bbb">
    <div id="actor" onclick="testParent(this)">
      test parent
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

JAVASCRIPT-

```
testParent = function(obj){
 alert($(obj).closest(".p").attr('id'));
}
```